# How to Upload both Aab and Apk file at google play Developer Api?

Tags: android, google-api, google-play, apk, publish

When creating an MDM (Mobile Device Management) application using the Android Management API for full device management, I encounter an issue while attempting to programmatically upload the APK or AAB file through the Google Developer API.

Here is My Code(node js):

```
    const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
        keyFile: CONFIG.DeveloperServiceApiFilePath,
        scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher'],
    });

    // Create an Android Publisher API client
    const androidPublisherClient = google.androidpublisher({
        version: 'v3',
        auth: auth,
    });


 try {

        // Create a new edit for your app listing
        const createEditResponse = await androidPublisherClient.edits.insert({
            packageName: packageName,
        });

        // Get the newly created editId from the response
        const editId = createEditResponse.data.id;
        console.log(editId, packageName)
        // Set the MIME type for AAB files

        // Upload the APK using the publisher.edits.apks.upload method with the editId
        try {
            const uploadResponse = await androidPublisherClient.edits.apks.upload({
                packageName: packageName,
                editId: editId,
                media: {
                    // mimeType: 'application/vnd.android.package-archive',
                    mimeType: 'application/octet-stream',
                    body: fs.createReadStream(filePath),
                },
            });
            console.log('File uploaded successfully.');
            console.log('Version code:', uploadResponse.data.versionCode);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("Error: ", error.message)
        }

        return {
            packageName: packageName,
            version: versionName
        };
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error: ", error.message)
    }
```

**The error message I receive is "APK cannot be analyzed using aapt dump badging" when trying to upload the AAB file.**

If you could kindly guide me on how to How to Upload Aab and Apk files at google play Developer Api or provide any relevant code examples, it would be greatly appreciated.